# INSERT INTO / UPDATE table when there is no unique constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Suppose that there is an excel list of 20+ columns wwhich are Car Part Details(part no, model, year etc..), Vehicle Details (brand, model, make, year etc), Engine Details (Brand, Model, Make, etc.) individually.

I would like to pass them to my relational database (in MS SQL SERVER 2008). Naturally I have tables for Car Part, Vehicle, and Engine to avoid duplicate entry since a vehicle has many car parts.

I don't have any kind of id in excel to match them within my tables. Car Part number is a Unique Constraint so I have no problem with that. But when it comes to Engine table or Vehicle table, I have no Unique Constraint for them even if I try to use multiple columns. Because all might be the same except manufacturing year.

In this case, I have no chance except checking all the columns within my table if they exits, in order to insert into / update them and it doesn't make sense to me. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: What if did a `SELECT * FROM your_table`, copied the results, and pasted the results in the respective spreadsheet? Fix the data how you want it in Excel and then import the data into SQL using the Import/Export Wizard. I would import the data into a table with a slightly different name and only drop the old table when you are happy with the new one.

Comment: I cannot import data from excel as it is because excel repeats same vehicle details for two different car parts. I have to update these tables every once in a while so I cannot export to excel, drop and recreate tables every single time. I need a way to check if the vehicle record exits within my vehicle table but there is no unique constraint to check that. There should be an easy way to do this ,without exporting them to excel with their primary keys and vlookup my values in excel and see which vehicle records are new in my excel.